# Controlled execution of For Each activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a scenario wherein we have a config table the values of which are passed as parameters to a web activity :

[image]

The iterations needs to be either sequential as in case 1 or parallel as in case 2 or hybrid (1st iteration and then next 2 iterations parallelly)

So how to achieve the above scenario of making the For each iterations either sequential or parallel at run time based on some configs

Comment: The Sequential checkbox is not paramaterizable, so you'll need separate ForEach activities. And since you can't put a ForEach inside an If or Switch, you'll need separate pipelines. So one design would be an outer pipeline that analyzes the data (probably best with an Azure Function) and then calls the appropriate child pipeline based on the results.

Comment: We do something very similar with parent / child pipeline, the `range` function to iterate over the sequence ids, a Filter activity and a child pipeline with an Object parameter.  Let me know if you want me to work up an example.

Comment: Hey @wBob, it would be great to see an example !

Answer (score 1):

We do something similar with parent and child pipelines but the points to note are as follows:

- use a Lookup activity to get records for the scenario you want
- use a sequential For Each activity with the `range` function to generate the unique sequence numbers, eg 1 to 3
- use a Filter activity inside the For Each to filter all items from the current scenario to the current sequence id only, ie filter on 1, then 2, then 3 etc
- again inside the For Each activity, call a child pipeline which takes an object parameter.  The object value is the output value from the Filter
- the child pipeline has a For Each activity which loops through each item in the input object parameter.

The pattern for the parent pipeline is as follows:

[image]

The pattern for the child pipeline is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Any view on this @Nandan?  I'm trying to use this 'boxes and lines' format for documenting ADF templates / examples but it only kind of works for simple examples.  In terms of the flow, does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

As rightly mentioned by Joel, `ForEach` activity cannot be parameterized to achieve a runtime property config.

What you can do is have Two Similar pipeline in (Parent-child formation using `Execute pipeline` Activity) with only change being `Sequential` or `Batch Count` property already hard set in corresponding `ForEach` Activity. Now you can use `If` or `Switch` activity to determine the scenario and following which run the corresponding `Execute Pipeline` activity.